# How to place order by clause criteria query

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, criteria

This is mycode:

```
       public List<Veiculo> getAll()
   {

      CriteriaQuery<Veiculo> criteria = this.entityManager
            .getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Veiculo.class);
      return this.entityManager.createQuery(  
            criteria.select(criteria.from(Veiculo.class))).getResultList();
   }
```

Now, I need  a order by clause that criteria query.

```
orderby veiculo.getServico
```

I try, but dont work

```
   public List<Veiculo> getAll()
   {

      CriteriaQuery<Veiculo> criteria = this.entityManager
            .getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Veiculo.class);
      return this.entityManager.createQuery(  
            criteria.select(criteria.from(Veiculo.class)).orderBy(getVeiculo().getServico())).getResultList();
   }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following rewrite should work for you, didn't compile so consider as an exemplary meta-code

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = this.entityManager
                .getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Veiculo> criteria = cb.createQuery(Veiculo.class);
    Root<Veiculo> root = criteria.from(Veiculo.class);
    return this.entityManager.createQuery(
                 criteria.select(root).orderBy(cb.asc(root.get("servico"))))
           .getResultList();
```